# check if literal object included in other object with Built-in API

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6

I mean Object-B is included in Object-A, when all attributes of Object-B are included in the object-A and its values are the same in the object-A.

```js
 var obj_b={a:1,d:3}
 var obj_a={a:1,b:22,c:33,d:3} //--> obj_b includes in obj_a
 var obj_c={a:1,f:4};

isIncluded=(small,big)=>Object.keys(small).every((k)=>big[k] === small[k])
console.log(
 'Does "obj-b" included in "obj-a"  ? ',isIncluded(obj_b,obj_a)   
)
console.log(
 'Does "obj-c" included in "obj-a"  ? ',isIncluded(obj_c,obj_a)   
)
```

### My question  is:

Does ES6/ES7 has built-in API **more elegant and brief** for that?

For example, to extend object from origin, ES6 brought `Object.assign(o1,o2)`?

Is there something like `Object.isInclude(o1,o2)`?

Comment: No, there is nothing like that in ECMAScript, and it would be weird is there was something, providing that this is very specific thing that is simply not needed to be generic. Create helper function like you did, it's okay.

Comment: You can't get more brief than what you wrote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not. Your solution is already brief and elegant, although it could be golfed by another 4 characters.

```
const isSubObject = (small,big)=>Object.keys(small).every(k=>big[k]===small[k]);
```

Comment: We could just extend the `Object.prototype` with the `isIncluded` function, but we could already do that in ES5.. 
so I thought of silly way of extending the built-in `Object` and adding the function to the child class :| ...  https://jsfiddle.net/cswl/qnnp1vcb/